# Classic ASP and Javascript Integration

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, youtube-api

I'm currently using Classic ASP and youtube javascript API in order to pull information of videos and store them into a database, however I need to know if some of the next steps are possible, or if I would have to convert to another language.

The information I am seeking to download into my SQL 2012 Database currently exceeds the maximum space allowed, meaning I can only send about 50 of my 1700 results (and growing) each time. Prior to the space cap, I would simply keep running the next page function until there is no more pagetokens and simply upload all the data, however, now I must do it in small steps.

My application currently works like this: Javascript creates hidden forms->Forms are submitted->classic ASP queries form and moves information to database

By directly editing the code I can modify which 50 results I send to the classic ASP, but I'd like to be able to do this without modifying code.

So my question is this: Is it possible to send a url query of sorts to javascript so that I know what results I have sent? Or is there a better way to circumvent the space issue aside from rerunning the javascript each time?

The error I get when attempting to spend too much information is:

```
Request object error 'ASP 0104 : 80004005'

Operation not Allowed
```

I apologize if this question seems a little vague as I'm not entirely sure how to word this without writing a 5 paragraph essay.

Comment: When the forms are submitted, is the ASP on a different page or the same page as the javascript?

Comment: And what happens when the ASP is finished with a set?  Does it redirect back to the page with the javascript and forms?

Comment: at the moment no, as I'm manually changing the code in order to go through each page of results. What I'm currently planning would most likely need to go back to the page though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a redirect on the ASP doing the downloading.  The redirect can go back to the javascript page and include the number of results processed in the url like so:

```
Response.Redirect "javascript.asp?numResults=" & numberOfResultsSentSoFar
```

Then on the javascript page include some ASP to extract the number of results processed

```
dim resultsProcessed = Request.QueryString("numResults")
```

Then you can feed it into javascript like so:

```
var currentResultIndex = <%=resultsProcessed%>;
```

However, a better way might be to use AJAX to send the first 50 results and wait for a response from the ASP and then send the next 50.

Comment: I do believe I saw a few ways to retrieve querystrings with Javascript so that may help. But I've heard of AJAX on many occasions and if you believe AJAX would be much better do you have any suggestions on where to start learning it? Or is it simple enough to just youtube/google tutorials?

Comment: I don't have much experience with using pure javascript for AJAX but you can look up some tutorials on google.  jQuery makes it easier to use so you could look into that.  If you feel like using it, look up jQuery.post() in jQuery's api.